# Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Calculate $\lim\limits_{c\to 0^+} \int_{ca}^{cb}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to integrate by parts but it has not been very effective.

Comment: Are you sure about the domain of $f$? It doesn't match with the integrand! There should be a problem!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We suppose $0 < a < b$.

For $\epsilon > 0$, you can find $\delta > 0$ such that for $\vert x \vert \le \delta$ you have $\vert f(x)-f(0) \vert \le \epsilon$ (by continuity of $f$ at $0$).

Then for $\vert c \vert \max(a,b) \le \delta$, we have $[ca,cb] \subset [0,\delta]$. Hence:
$$\left\vert \int_{ca}^{cb} \frac{f(x)}{x} dx - \int_{ca}^{cb} \frac{f(0)}{x} dx \right\vert\le \int_{ca}^{cb} \frac{\vert f(x)-f(0) \vert}{x} dx \le \epsilon \int_{ca}^{cb} \frac{dx}{x}=\epsilon \ln(\frac{b}{a})$$

The RHS goes to $0$ as $\epsilon$ goes to $0$. So $$\lim\limits_{c \to 0^+} \int_{ca}^{cb} \frac{f(x)}{x} dx =\int_{ca}^{cb} \frac{f(0)}{x} dx=\color{red}{f(0)\ln(\frac{b}{a})}$$

**This proof is only assuming that $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ and continuous at $0$.**

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** Substitute $$u := \frac{x}{c}, \quad du = \frac{dx}{c}.$$

Answer (score 2):

we have

$$g(c) = \int_{ca}^{cb} {\frac{{f(x)}}{x}dx} $$

now use the following substitution

$$\eqalign{
  & u = \frac{x}{c}  \cr 
  & du = \frac{1}{c}dx \cr} $$

to get

$$\eqalign{
  & g(c) = \int_{ca}^{cb} {\frac{{f(x)}}{x}dx}  = \int_a^b {\frac{{f(cu)}}{{cu}}cdu}   \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = \int_a^b {\frac{{f(cu)}}{u}du}  = \left. {f(cu)\ln (u)} \right|_a^b - c\int_a^b {\ln (u)f'(cu)du}   \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = \left( {f(cb)\ln (b) - f(ca)\ln (a)} \right) - c\int_a^b {\ln (u)f'(cu)du}  \cr} $$

Where we **assumed** that $f$ is **continuous differentiable**. Now letting $c$ goes to zero and using the continuity of $f$ and ${f'}$ at zero we have

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{c \to 0} g(c) = f(0)\ln (\frac{b}{a})$$

Comment: We don't know if $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: Yeah! you are right! :) This solution is based on this assumption!

Comment: I mentioned the assumption in the solution procedure. :)
Thanks for mentioning but that's not fair for a down vote!. :)

Comment: @H. R. In fact you even need a bit more than $f$ differentiable. You need $f$ differentiable and $f^\prime$ integrable.

Comment: Are you satisfied with continuous differentiable! :)

Comment: I didn't downvote. But I wanted to point this out because in some ways the problem is more demanding without the additional hypotheses.

Comment: Yeah, you are right again! :) However I just wanted to write down this solution as I was in the middle of it! :) Please at least up vote! It doesn't deserve down vote for god sake! :D

Comment: @H. R. Agree with your comment on downvote. I even don't understand why those exist! Or at least downvoters should have to associate a comment.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net "I even don't understand why those exist!" To remedy to this lack of understanding, try visiting meta. "Or at least downvoters should have to associate a comment." No, as has been discussed to death multiple times.

Comment: I did downvote: When I did, the answer did not include the caveat that it additionally assumed that $f$ is continuously differentiable, and so the answer was misleading about the nature of the problem, which in its full generality is a little more technically demanding. Unless a solution is visibly nonsense, I usually prefer to include an explanation/constructive criticism (though as Did points out, this is not obligatory), but in this case, Simon S' first comment already explained the issue.

Comment: Anyway, I've rescinded my downvote now that the caveat has been added. I only knew to do this because I happened upon this question by chance---I imagine the other downvoter did not.

Comment: @ Travis: Thank you by the way for constructive criticism. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $f$ is continuous at $0$, so that we can say that over the interval of interest, $f$ satisfies
$$
\frac{f(0) - \epsilon}{x} \leq \frac{f(x)}{x} \leq \frac{f(0) + \epsilon}{x}
$$
when $c$ is sufficiently small.